# Constants for special characters?

Tags: java, apache

Is there any common library that provides constants for often used delimiter chars (like `,;"`), similar to `StringUtils.SPACE/EMPTY/LF/CR`?

Comment: You want a whole library for 4-5 String values?

Comment: No but `apache.lang3` contains as I wrote constants for space, empty, linefeed. Maybe I missed something and any common/apache string util contains also separator chars?

Comment: @membersound There's also [System.lineSeparator()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator()). You might use anything as a delmititer, so it's up to you to write your constants file (if you want one).

Comment: It is 2017 now. Is there any such class available?

Comment: See [*Does Java define constants for any characters such as SPACE?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33183525/642706). I posted source code declaring constants for all of ASCII in [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77248280/642706).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are names but not as constants.

```
    for (int cp = 32; cp < 48; ++cp) {
        System.out.printf("%c : %s%n", cp, Character.getName(cp));
    }

  : SPACE
! : EXCLAMATION MARK
" : QUOTATION MARK
# : NUMBER SIGN
$ : DOLLAR SIGN
% : PERCENT SIGN
& : AMPERSAND
' : APOSTROPHE
( : LEFT PARENTHESIS
) : RIGHT PARENTHESIS
* : ASTERISK
+ : PLUS SIGN
, : COMMA
- : HYPHEN-MINUS
. : FULL STOP
/ : SOLIDUS
```

It is cumbersome working with constants, so I do not think someone made the effort.

You could do it yourself, maybe generating the enum using the Character.getName from above, replacing blank in the name with an underscore.

```
enum Chars {
    COMMA(','),
    SEMICOLON(';'),
    EXCLAMATION_SIGN('!');

    private final int ch;
    private static Map<Integer, Chars> map = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        for (Chars c : Chars.values()) {
            map.put(c.ch, c);
        }
    }

    private Chars(int ch) { this.ch = ch; }

    public int toCodePoint() { return ch; }

    public static Chars fromCodePoint(int cp) {
        return map.get(cp);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() { return new String(new int[]{ ch }, 0, 1); }
}
```

Mind, there an enum has a name getter too, for "COMMA" etc.

Comment: It is 2017 now. Is there any such class available?

Comment: @fatherazrael [Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77248280/642706)